# How to delete woo commerce order pragmatically?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to delete an order from database i was tried using bellow function but this is not working.can any body tell me how to delete an order from db using order id.

```
<?php wc_delete_order_item( absint( $order_id ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Orders are just regular posts:

```
wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
```

Comment: For reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/

Comment: is their a way to delete order based on userid ?

Comment: It's incorrect for HPOS WooCommerce feature.